# How to uninstall Wish Application

Tags: windows-8.1, uninstall, unwanted-application

ALL,

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop that I recently put some updates on.

Unfortunately it looks like I got some stupid "Wish Application" pinned to my task bar (the icon looks like an Alladin lamp).

I tied to uninstall it from the Control Panel, but it doesn't list it.

Does anybody know how to get rid of it?

TIA!

Comment: many applications come with an uninstaller.exe that is in the same folder as the program itself. Are you able to locate the directory where it is installed?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid, nope. I tried to "UnPin from the Task Bar", and no the icon is completely gone

Comment: Can you see it running in the task manager?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid, nope it is not running. I guess its just PUS (potentially unwanted software). Which I don't want.

Comment: what happens when you click on the icon in the taskbar?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid, the menu with the 2 choices: "Wish Application" and "Unping from the TaskBar". I chose the second and its not disappear. I can try to run Malware Bytes...

Comment: what happens when you run the first choice?